# Spinning thread takes 20,000 CPU cycles to see atomic write on Xeon CPU

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, x86, intel

I have a thread writing to an atomic variable and a second thread spinning on it. I time from the write to detecting the change.

I am seeing latencies up to 80,000 with many between 20,000 and 40,000. This should take ~350 cycles. The threads are pinned, I use acquire-release semantics etc.

The code: https://godbolt.org/z/ETM1YnTrb and pasted below. If anyone could confirm my observations, that would be appreciated.

To investigate I focused on the hot-spinning while loop:

```
while(true)
{
    if(_trigger.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) [[unlikely]]
    {
        const uint64_t read_ts = rdtscp();
    }
```

Was the spinning thread getting re-scheduled by the OS? Or, was the thread still spinning but not seeing the value of `_trigger`?

I took a timestamp on each loop iteration and saved to an array. On a high latency I print the write timestamp, the read timestamp and the loop iteration timestamps which occurred between.

```
while(true)
{
    // Take a timestamp here and store to an array/circular buffer

    if(_trigger.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) [[unlikely]]
    {
        const uint64_t read_ts = GetNow();
        const uint64_t latency = read_ts - write_ts;

        if(latency > N)
        {
             // print write ts
             // loop iteration timestamps
             // print read ts
    }
```

I observed there are hundreds of loop iterations between the write and the read:

```
write_ts                  392525979198029
iteration (37898) loop_ts 392525979198029
.
. 
.
iteration (37932) loop_ts 392525979198029
iteration (37933) loop_ts 392525979198029
.
iteration (38500) loop_ts 392525979198029
.
iteration (38545) loop_ts 392525979198029
read_ts                   392525979221689
core_id (1) write -> read (23660) loop -> read (196) soft (0) hard (0) vol (0) invol (0) sig (0) kernel_us (0)
```

So the read thread wasn't getting rescheduled unless it happened after the final loop ts and before the read ts.

```
while(true)
{
    const uint64_t loop_ts = GetNow();
    // Delay starts here

    if(_trigger.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) [[unlikely]]
    {
        // delay ends here
        const uint64_t read_ts = GetNow();
```

The above shows the spinning thread took 23,000 cycles from the final loop timestamp to reach the read timestamp?!

I added a macro to toggle `getrusage()` to measure context switches and whilst some did occasionally occur, many times there were no context switches when this occurred. I also added a macro to switch between tsc and nanoseconds/chrono.

I assume there's three possibilities?

1. Spinning thread is context-switched after the loop iteration timestamp and the read timestamp (but getrusage suggests otherwise)
2. Timers across CPU cores are out of synch (but I get the same using chrono and nanoseconds)
3. The CPU is taking ages to present the atomic variable to the spinning thread

My CPU is an Intel Xeon W-1370P @ 3.60GHz. It has one socket, 8 cores, 16 with hyperthreading. I believe cores 0-7 map to cores 8 to 15, so I did my test using 1 and 6.

If I un-define rusage (and nanoseconds) and run `perf` I get:

[image]

```
sudo perf stat -B --delay=1000 ./my_app
```

So I don't think this is about context switches?

Does anyone know what's going on?

Ubuntu 22.04

Kernel is: `6.5.0-14-generic`

Compiler is Clang 16 with `-O3 -march=native -mprefer-vector-width=128`

Full code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <sys/resource.h>

//#define USE_RUSAGE
//#define USE_NANOSECONDS

using TimePoint = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;

uint64_t GetNow();
uint64_t rdtscp();
void set_thread_affinity(const int8_t core_id);
void check_latency(int core_id, uint64_t ts_1, uint64_t ts_2);


static const size_t WRITE_THREAD_CPU_ID_AFFINITY = 6;
static const size_t READ_THREAD_CPU_ID_AFFINITY = 1;


alignas(64) std::atomic<bool> _trigger{false};
int _core_id;
std::array<uint64_t, 65536> _loop_ts;
alignas(64) std::atomic<uint64_t> _write_ts;


void hot_spin()
{
    set_thread_affinity(READ_THREAD_CPU_ID_AFFINITY);

#ifdef USE_RUSAGE
    struct rusage usage_1;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &usage_1);
#endif
    uint16_t loop_count{0};

    while(true)
    {
        const uint64_t loop_start = GetNow();
        _loop_ts[loop_count] = loop_start;

        if(_trigger.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) [[unlikely]]
        {
            const uint64_t read_ts = GetNow();
            const uint64_t latency = read_ts - _write_ts.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

#ifdef USE_RUSAGE
            struct rusage usage_2;
            getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &usage_2);
#endif

            if(latency >= 20'000 && latency <= 100'000'000)
            {
                std::cout << "write_ts                  " << _write_ts << std::endl;

                for(size_t i = 0; i < _loop_ts.size(); ++i)
                {
                    if(_loop_ts[i] >= _write_ts)
                    {
                        std::cout << "iteration (" << i << ") loop_ts " << _write_ts << std::endl;
                    }
                }

                std::cout << "read_ts                   " << read_ts << std::endl;

#ifdef USE_RUSAGE
                const uint64_t vol_cs = usage_2.ru_nvcsw - usage_1.ru_nvcsw;
                const uint64_t invol_cs = usage_2.ru_nivcsw - usage_1.ru_nivcsw;

                const uint64_t soft = usage_2.ru_minflt - usage_1.ru_minflt;
                const uint64_t hard = usage_2.ru_majflt - usage_1.ru_majflt;

                printf("core_id (%d) write -> read (%lu) loop -> read (%lu) soft (%lu) hard (%lu) vol (%lu) invol (%lu) sig (%ld) kernel_us (%ld)\n", _core_id, latency, read_ts - loop_start, soft, hard, vol_cs, invol_cs, usage_2.ru_nsignals - usage_1.ru_nsignals, usage_2.ru_stime.tv_usec - usage_1.ru_stime.tv_usec);
#else
                printf("core_id (%d) write -> read (%lu) loop -> read (%lu)\n", _core_id, latency, read_ts - loop_start);
#endif
            }

#ifdef USE_RUSAGE
            usage_1 = usage_2;
#endif
            
            _trigger = false;
        }

        ++loop_count;
    }
}

void write()
{
    const uint64_t write_ts = GetNow();
    _write_ts.store(write_ts, std::memory_order_release);
    _trigger.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void waitUntilPtrReset()
{
    while(_trigger){}
}

int main()
{
    set_thread_affinity(WRITE_THREAD_CPU_ID_AFFINITY);

    std::thread t(&hot_spin);
    t.detach();

    while(true)
    {
        write();
        waitUntilPtrReset();
    }

    return 0;
}

#ifdef USE_NANOSECONDS

uint64_t GetNow()
{
    const TimePoint now = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const auto tmp_1 = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now);
    const auto tmp_2 = tmp_1.time_since_epoch();
    return tmp_2.count(); 
}

#else

uint64_t GetNow()
{
    return rdtscp();
}

uint64_t rdtscp()
{
    uint32_t lo, hi;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtscp" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi) : : "%rcx");
    return (((uint64_t)hi << 32) | lo);
}

#endif

inline void set_thread_affinity(const int8_t core_id)
{
    cpu_set_t  mask;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(core_id, &mask);
    const int this_process = 0;
    const int result = sched_setaffinity(this_process, sizeof(mask), &mask);

    if(result != 0)
    {
        std::abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: The linked code seems to crash `Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV`

Comment: @273K I assumed that's due to the CPU affinities or permissions on Godbolt's server? That exact code works fine on my local machine, just might need changing the affinity IDs.

Comment: @273K: Runs fine for me `g++ -O2` on Arch GNU/Linux on my i7-6700k Skylake CPU, 4c8t.  I also see a long run of `iteration (21218) loop_ts 30603304641541799` lines with the same timestamp but different iteration counts, but I haven't read the code yet to see if slow I/O could explain that.  Spewing I/O could easily block a thread and lead to a long pause, unless it's only done outside the timed intervals.

Comment: @PeterCordes No 20,000+ delay? Or you just mean no crashing like on Godbolt?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes I was concerned with the same timestamp on each loop iteration too. This was the reason I added the chrono code, in case an issue with tsc but the same thing happens.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The shortened thread task is `while (true) if (trigger_) trigger_ = false;`. Of course it will spin a lot until another thread gets running.

Comment: @273K The reader thread takes 20,000 cycles to see a write from another core on the same processor (excluding logging). I see latencies up to 80,000 cycles. It should take ~350 cycles max.

Comment: The both threads are writing and reading `trigger_` and spinning, which one are you talking about?

Comment: @273K The writer sets the boolean to true, then it spins on `waitUntilPtrReset()`. Meanwhile the reader spins, waiting to see the change. Then it sets to false, so the writer repeats. So they perform write-read-write-read-write-read....

Comment: `waitUntilPtrReset()` does not block, it's spinning. The both threads spin-read-write and spin-read.

Comment: @273K Okay, i've edited my comment. It spins. My point is you there aren't multiple writes happening without a read.

Comment: @273K I've just added a `sleep(100ns)` between the write and spin, in the FOR loop in `main()`. Makes no difference, still see the same high latencies.

Comment: @273K Thanks. I've just made a change to call `sched_getcpu()` immediately after the affinity and check it worked.  It's passing so I presume the affinity succeeded?

Comment: @273K I don't fully understand. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: I was mistaken, `sched_setaffinity()` does smth similar to `sched_yield()` for switching to a desired core. An extra call to `sched_yield()` is not required.

Comment: @PeterCordes are there any specific hardware counters you think could help? I could lookup the Intel codes and add them to Perf command (assuming Perf allows custom event code args).

Comment: Thread creation and maybe thread detaching are system calls, hence main thread is blocked, and hot_spin thread can run and spin at this time.

Comment: @intrigued_66: I looked at `machine_clears.memory_ordering` but it didn't seem excessive.  Spinning without `pause`, we already expect counts for that.  Perhaps `mem_trans_retired.load_latency_gt_512` to count really high latency loads?  But unless the raw counters support a higher threshold like 1024, we already expect some loads to take that long even with just one other core contending for it.  `page-faults` stopped growing soon after startup, since your array is small and fixed size.

Comment: @PeterCordes but if I understood correctly, this latency issue doesn't appear with your system, so your counters would all be fine anyway? Or you do observe the problem?

Comment: I get plenty of outputs like `core_id (0) write -> read (90358) loop -> read (175)`.  That one coming after a long run of `iteration... loop_ts` lines in case that's significant (that's what I initially though I was looking for), with the interval between the `write_ts 30606865905753576` and `read_ts 30606865905843934` being `90358`.  Others like `core_id (0) write -> read (49424) loop -> read (49370)` are common, with both "read" numbers high (from 30k to 60k), but some others with the first read number high and the next low.

Comment: Could this just be interrupt handlers causing occasional delay spikes?  The rate of spew on the terminal seems higher when I'm pressing keyboard keys, but kind of settles if I take my hands off for a few seconds.

Comment: @PeterCordes awesome. Okay so you observe the problem too. The problem still occurs without the logging and loop timestamps. I only added it to see how many loop iterations occur after the write. I presume you agree it shouldn't take this long?

Comment: @PeterCordes RE interrupts, if you un comment `#define USE_RUSAGE `, this should enable getrusage and it will also output the number of context switches per loop when the high latency occurs. However, this is based on my assumptions how getrusage works.

Comment: Right, inter-thread latency with low contention should only be a few hundred TSC cycles (on my CPU where max turbo is 4.2 GHz, TSC ticks at 4008 MHz).  I also tried setting an EPP=balance_performance which on my system doesn't do turbo, and only goes up to 3.9GHz with any number of cores active.  (IDK what's up with that, the stock frequency is 4.0 GHz, but anyway.)  So it wasn't from CPU frequency transitions.

Comment: `getrusage` and context-switch counters don't seem relevant.  An IRQ handler doesn't count as a context switch since it returns to the same user-space process.  Linux's per-core `current` variable won't change.  At least not for an IRQ handler top-half; the bottom-half (if any) has to get scheduled somewhere but it could be on a core that's not already busy.  Check `/proc/interrupts`.  There are at least local timer interrupts on every core.

Comment: @PeterCordes ahhhhh. What's the best way to measure them? Interrupts can last that long?!

Comment: With Spectre and MDS mitigations enabled, sure.  The microcode to flush branch-prediction and internal microarchitectural buffers can take significant time, 30k cycles seems reasonable.  IDK if there's a cheap way to check that one occurred recently; parsing `/proc/interrupts` is obviously way too expensive and more timer interrupts would probably happen while you were doing it. (Or while the kernel was generating the text data.)  Normally we just discard outliers when microbenchmarking unless we've taken extreme measures to isolate a core and use specialized NO_HZ stuff to not run interrupts.

Comment: @PeterCordes let me check this and report back? If I use no_hz on grub command line but it still happens, does that eliminate interrupts?

Comment: https://docs.kernel.org/timers/no_hz.html - you'd need a kernel built with `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y`, which the docs say is normally not recommended, because enabling / disabling the timer that periodically raises interrupts adds more overhead than it saves in most workloads.  And presumably you'd need `isolcpus` or something else to steer device-driver interrupts away from the cores you're pinning to.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've just come across the `linux lowlatency` package from apt-get. However, I can't find what it includes. Do you know it/does it include kconfig settings like the one you just mentioned?

Comment: @rare77: On Ubuntu?  No idea.  Check `/proc/config.gz` after booting its kernel, or `/boot/config-whatever` if it installs a copy of the kernel config there.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, this is mostly likely just interrupt handlers causing occasional delay spikes on one of the cores separate from the actual inter-thread communication.

Normally you should just discard outliers from microbenchmarks because of things like interrupts.  (And if you don't disable turbo, the possibility of CPU frequency transitions pausing the clock for a few microseconds while a new voltage stabilizes.)

I can reproduce it on my desktop (i7-6700k Arch GNU/Linux, kernel 6.5).  The rate of spew on the terminal seems higher when I'm pressing keyboard keys, but kind of settles if I take my hands off for a few seconds.  (Not to zero, but to a lower rate of disruption).  And there seems to be a correlation between hitting more keys and another burst of output.  Not as strongly with moving the mouse; maybe the IRQ handler for that is on a different core than the two these threads are running on.

An IRQ handler doesn't count as a context switch. Before Spectre/Meltdown and other reasons for KPTI, the page-tables wouldn't have changed.  And with KPTI, it's just changing between the with-kernel-mappings vs. without-kernel-mappings version of the same process's page tables.  Linux's per-core `current` variable doesn't change.  (The bottom-half of an interrupt handler that needs one *does* get scheduled and require a context switch.  But local timer interrupts don't need a bottom-half.  Also, a bottom-half could maybe run on a different core.)

---

To run processes without the local timer interrupt firing 100x or 1000x a second, you need a kernel configured with `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y` (https://docs.kernel.org/timers/no_hz.html).  The docs say that's normally not recommended, because enabling / disabling the timer that periodically raises interrupts adds more overhead than it saves in most workloads.

And presumably you'd need `isolcpus` or something else to steer device-driver interrupts away from the cores you're pinning to.

> Interrupts can last that long?!

With Spectre and MDS mitigations enabled, sure. The microcode to flush branch-prediction and internal microarchitectural buffers can take significant time, 30k cycles seems reasonable.